# Regexp with .exec not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match 3 letters and 3 digits with `regexp` and `exec`. But I dont get any result. Any idea what is wrong? The code is:

```
var regnr = "This is the pattern to match: WBJ124";
var patt = new RegExp("^\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}\b*$");
var sequence = '';
var grps = patt.exec(regnr);
if(grps!=null){
  sequence = grps[0];
}
```

`sequence` is empty, but I expect it to be `WBJ124`

Best Regards

Comment: @anubhava Does not work as well :/

Comment: @anubhava Please wright an answer with example, maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: [Visual View of Reg Exp](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Cb%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%5Cd%7B3%7D%5Cb*%24%2F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few mistakes in your regex like using `^` and `$` when you are matching a substring in a longer string. Also you are using `RegExp` object that accepts a string literal hence requires double escaping.

You can use:

```
var regnr = "This is the pattern to match: WBJ124";
var patt = /\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}\b/; // or new RegExp("\\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{3}\\b")
var grps = patt.exec(regnr);
```