# JS Regex RegExp pattern with exec function not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, pattern-matching

I have tried to debug this the best I can and followed MDN's documentation to the best of my ability. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

I don't believe it is a character escape issue as noted here. [Regexp with .exec not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336156/regexp-with-exec-not-working)

***What am I trying to do?*** : I am trying to use this regex pattern that seems to work in regex101 : `[a-zA-Z0-9.\\s]+` to match any user input that is allowed and then console log those matches.

***What is the problem? :*** The regex pattern will work with: `const reg = '[a-zA-Z0-9.\\\\s]+';` and validates properly in my form input. However, when trying to extract each individual match I am running into problems. There seems to be 2 ways to extract matches from a regex object and I have attempted both described by MDN doc. When trying to use a literal or RegExp object with this pattern and the `.exex()` function I either get errors or it does not correctly pattern match. Even when I did get one pattern to almost work it would return `null`.

***What have I done to debug? :*** I tried every combination of strings, literals, and constructor combinations I can think of and nothing is seeming to work. I tried to console log and attempt each method according to MDN and nothing is working. I tried to make sure I was using correctly character escaping as well. The reason I have my regexp in a string instead of a literal is because for some reason it is being rendered in the HTML incorrectly. When I use the only regex pattern in strings that seems to work it is rendered in my HTML differently and I checked using inspect element.

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

**I only kept code in that was working. My regexp I attempted and other code is commented out with notes.**

***Pictures and Code:***
https://pastebin.com/M2dxHpJd

```
import ChatBot from './ChatBot';

const ChatBotCard = (props) => {

    //Works but is a string and not a literal? 
    const reg = '[a-zA-Z0-9.\\\\s]+';

    //Not working
    //const reg = /[a-zA-Z0-9.\\s]+/;
    //const reg = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9.\\\\s]+', 'gm');
    //const regexp ='[a-zA-Z0-9.\\\\s]+';
    //const reg = new RegExp( regexp );
    //const reg = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9.\\s]+/);
    //const reg = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9.\\s]+");
    
    

    const [chatBotStatus, setChatBotStatus] = useState(false)
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('')
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
    const [errmssg, setErrmssg] = useState('');

    const formHandle = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        let input = document.forms["botForm"]["formInput"].value;

        // Attempt 1: 

        // Will not work for just string its not an object
        // Gives TypeError : reg.exec is not a function
        // let result = reg.exec(x);

        // Attempt 2:

        // So we need to use RegExp to use exec() method instead
        // I can not get the RegExp to render right in the HTML.
        // I think the / before and after is being rendered with it
        // This makes the expression invalid and exec() will return null ? 
        // Exec: Executes a search for a match in a string. It returns an array of information or null on a mismatch.
        
        /* let result;

        if((result = reg.exec(input)) == null)
        {
            console.log('Result array is null');
            console.log('Result: '+ result);
        }

        while ((result = reg.exec(input)) !== null) {
           
            let msg = 'Found a match ' + result[0] + '. ';
            msg += 'Next match starts at ' + reg.lastIndex;
            console.log(msg);

            console.log('Result array is not null');
            console.log('Result: '+ result);
        }  */

        // Attempt 3:

        // This also did not work but according to MDN
        // You can also use exec() without creating a RegExp object explicitly:
        // This also does not seem to work as expected
        //let result = /[a-zA-Z0-9.\\s]+/.exec(input);

        console.log("Form handle: input: " + input);
        console.log("Reg exp: " + reg);
        //console.log("Result is: " + result);
        

        // Additional error handling ( does not matter for regex )
        if ( input.length > 126)
        {
            setErrmssg('Shorten your question');
            setTimeout(() => {
                setErrmssg('');
              }, 3000);
            return false;
        }
        if ( input.length <= 1)
        {
            setErrmssg('Please, talk to the AI in a sentence more than 1 letter');
            setTimeout(() => {
                setErrmssg('');
              }, 3000);
            return false;
        }

        //Set data to call api 
        setUserInput(input);
        setToggle(true);
    }

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                backgroundColor: '#1B2524ff',
                border: '1px solid #212C50ff',
                height: '100%',
            }}
        >
            <form 
            
                name="botForm"
                onSubmit={formHandle} 
                style={{ 
                    display: 'flex', 
                    flexDirection: 'column', 
                    justifyContent: 'center', 
                    flexFlow: 'column wrap', 
                    alignItems: 'center', 
                    padding: '5px' 
                }}

            >
                <label
                    style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        color: '#3F646Dff', padding: '5px'
                    }}
                    for="search">

                    {props.message}
                </label>

                <input
                    required
                    pattern={reg}
                    minlength="1"
                    maxLength="200"
                    min="0"
                    max="0"
                    aria-label="Textbox max length 200 words"
                    name="formInput"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        border: '1px solid #025B79ff',
                        padding: '10px', color: '#19819Fff'
                    }}
                    id="search"
                    type="text"
                />

                <label></label>

                <input
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        border: '1px solid #19819Fff',
                        color: '#19819Fff',
                        padding: '10px',
                        cursor: 'pointer'
                    }}
                    type="submit"
                    value="Go">

                </input>

                <label 
                    name="errormssg"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        border: '1px solid #025B79ff',
                        padding: '10px', color: '#E0012Aff'
                    }}
                >
                    {errmssg}
                    
                </label>

                <input
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        border: '1px solid #025B79ff',
                        padding: '10px', color: '#19819Fff'
                    }}  
                    type="reset" 
                />

                <label
                    style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        color: '#3F646Dff',
                        padding: '5px',
                        fontWeight:'900',
                    }}
                    for="search">

                    {"You asked about : " + userInput}

                </label>
            </form>

            <ChatBot userInput={userInput} toggle={toggle} />

        </div>
    )
};
export default ChatBotCard
```

Good output:

[image: Correct Output]

[image: Working Output]

[image: Correct HTML]

Bad output:

[image: Incorrect HTML]

[image: Regex wont match]

Comment: Someone has suggested that the pattern is fine, and that the issue is I just need to use the regex for sanitization and then create a seperate split string function

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out Regex101 actually can generate their code for you lol. It works now and I can get matches. Basically I needed 2 regex patterns, one for sanitization , and a literal to grab matches for a single match group.

```
        const regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9.\\s]+/mg;


        while ((m = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
            // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
            if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }
            
            // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
            m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
                console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
            });
        }
```